how to open the azure devops signin screen from powershell?
I'm writing a powershell script to rotate my PAT in my devbox. Here's what I've done:
PS> .\Rotate-Pat.ps1

Here's the code in Check-PatValidity.ps1:
$env:PAT | az devops login --organization "https://dev.azure.com/$organization"

    $body = @{
        displayName = $organization
        scope = "vso.build vso.code_full vso.tokens vso.profile"
        validTo = (Get-Date).AddDays(7).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")
        allOrgs = $false
    } | ConvertTo-Json

    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/tokens/pats?api-version=7.1-preview.1" -Headers $headers -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType "application/json"
    
    $prettyJson = $response | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 2
    $prettyJson | Out-file $env:USERPROFILE\Downloads\patgenoutput.json -Encoding UTF8

    if ($response) {
        $newPat = $response.patToken.token
        Write-Output "New PAT: $newPat"
    }

Here's what I see as output (which is exactly the same as patgenoutput.json):

Looks like the html of Azure DevOps Login screen.
Questions:

Am I on the right track? If not, please point me in the right direction.
How to make the Azure DevOps login as an interactive session and get the access token to generate the PAT?


Hi @yasouser Any update on issue?

@Sridevi - the modified script worked perfectly! Thanks.

Alternatively, make use of below modified script that asks user to login interactively and generates bearer token to call Azure DevOps API for PAT creation:
$organization = "demodevOps25"

Write-Output "Logging into Azure..."
$loginOutput = az login --tenant "xxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com" --only-show-errors

try {
    $token = az account get-access-token --resource "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798" | ConvertFrom-Json
} catch {
    Write-Error "Failed to retrieve access token. Please check your Azure login status."
    exit
}

$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $($token.accessToken)"
    'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
}

$body = @(
    @{
        displayName = $organization
        scope = "vso.build vso.code_full vso.tokens vso.profile"
        validTo = (Get-Date).AddDays(7).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")
        allOrgs = $false
    }
) | ConvertTo-Json

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/tokens/pats?api-version=7.1-preview.1" `
                              -Headers $headers `
                              -Method Post `
                              -Body $body `
                              -ContentType "application/json"

if ($response -and $response.patToken) {
    $newPat = $response.patToken.token
    Write-Output "New PAT generated: $newPat"
    $outputPath = Join-Path $env:USERPROFILE "Downloads\patgenoutput.json"
    $response | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3 | Out-File $outputPath -Encoding UTF8
    Write-Output "PAT details saved to: $outputPath"
} else {
    Write-Error "Failed to generate PAT. Check the request body and API version."
}


Output:

To confirm that, I checked the saved file where new PAT details displayed successfully as below:

Azure DevOps Portal:


According to your description, you are trying to use the Pats - Create REST API to create a new PAT token with the old PAT token. However, it is not allowed to create a new token with an old PAT token.
You can check this document Manage personal access tokens (PATs) using REST API and the following Frequently asked questions (FAQs).

Q: Why do I need to authenticate with a Microsoft Entra token? Why is a PAT not enough?
A: With this PAT Lifecycle Management API, we opened the ability to create new PATs and revoke existing PATs. In the wrong hands, malicious actors could use this API to create multiple entry points into your organization’s Azure DevOps resources. By enforcing Microsoft Entra authentication, we hope to have this powerful API be more secure against this unauthorized usage.


Q: How can I regenerate/rotate PATs through the API? I saw that option in the UI, but I don’t see a similar method in the API.
A: Great question! The 'Regenerate' functionality available in the UI actually accomplishes a few actions, which are fully replicable through the API.
To rotate your PAT, do the following steps:

Understand the metadata of the PAT using a GET call,
Create a new PAT with the old PAT’s metadata using a POST call,
Revoke the old PAT using a DELETE call


Here are the steps to create an Azure AD application and create the PAT.

Register a new application under Microsoft Entra ID -> App Registrations in the Azure portal if you don't have one.


Select your application and navigate to API Permissions and select Azure DevOps -> check user_impersonation -> select Add permissions.



Add https://jwt.ms as Redirect URI.


Create a Client secret in the Certificates & secrets


Paste and access the following link in your browser to make authorization request to get the authorization code in the resulting URL:


https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?client_id=<appID>
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope= 499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default
&state=12345

Result:


Then you can generate the access token using authorization code in the following PowerShell script:

$tenantId = ''     
$clientId = ''   # check Application (client) ID and tenant Id from the app overview page
$clientSecret = ''  # the clientSecret from the step  4
$redirectUri="https://jwt.ms"

$organization = ""

$code=""   # the code from the step 5

$tokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token"

$body = @{
    grant_type    = "authorization_code"
    client_id     = $clientId
    client_secret = $clientSecret
    scope         = "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default"
    redirect_uri  = $redirectUri
    code          = $code
}

$headers = @{
    "Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}

# Make the POST request to get the access_token
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $tokenUrl -Headers $headers -Body $body
echo $response.access_token

# Create a PAT with the token
$body = @{
        displayName = $organization
        scope = "vso.build vso.code_full vso.tokens vso.profile"
        validTo = (Get-Date).AddDays(7).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")
        allOrgs = $false
    } | ConvertTo-Json
$accessHeader = @{
    'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + $response.access_token
}

$PATresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/tokens/pats?api-version=7.1-preview.1" -Headers $accessHeader -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType "application/json"


if ($PATresponse) {
   $newPat = $PATresponse.patToken.token
   Write-Output "New PAT: $newPat"
}


Please note that the authorization codes are short lived, typically expiring after about 10 minutes. So, if you want to get a new token, you can get a refresh_token first instead of getting an authorization code manually again. You can refer this question to get the refresh_token. For more details, please refer Microsoft identity platform and OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow
By the way, in your script, you are using the az devops login command and then use the Invoke-RestMethod call. However, the Invoke-RestMethod call won’t automatically inherit the login status from the az devops login command. The az devops login command is used to authenticate the Azure DevOps CLI, but it doesn’t directly affect the PowerShell session or the Invoke-RestMethod call. So, your Invoke-RestMethod call met the azure devops login page as you didn't login.

Thanks for the details steps. The AAD app step is needed only if my work account is not part of any tenant, right? Moreover, why do we need the redirect URI? And what is jwt.ms?

The AAD app step is need when we authenticate with Microsoft Entra tokens.  The redirect URI is needed when we request an authorization code  using the "authorization code” flow.

The jwt.ms is a simple web application that allows you to enter a JSON Web Token (JWT) and see its decoded claims. Using jwt.ms as a redirect URI lets you quickly view and debug the JWT returned by the authorization server. It's convenient for immediate token inspection. You can also use something like http://localhost as redirect URI.
